# How to apply padding attribute values to a whole table in Document Service?

Tags: google-apps-script

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to be able to apply padding attribute values to a whole table, and not just individual cells.

**Actual Behaviour**

I can apply padding attribute values to individual cells, but not the whole table.

**What I've Tried**

I create a table with:

```
var header_table = body.insertTable(0, cells);
```

This is using the [insertTable(childIndex, cells)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,String)) method of the [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) class and returns a [Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table).

The [Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table) class has a method called [setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setAttributes(Object)) which `"sets the element's attributes"`.

I then try and set the table's attributes with:

```
// BEGIN define style
var header_table_style = {};
header_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
header_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
header_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT] = 0;
header_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;
header_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP] = 0;
// END define style

// apply the style to the table
header_table.setAttributes(header_table_style);
```

The result is that the `font-family` is applied but not the `padding`, even thought `padding` is in the list of [Enum Attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute).

If I just try and apply the attributes to individual cells, however, the padding is applied:

```
header_table.getCell(0, 0).setAttributes(header_table_style);
header_table.getCell(0, 1).setAttributes(header_table_style);
```

**Questions**

**01)**  How can I apply attributes to a whole table?

**02)**  *Bonus Question:*  Why do all the official code examples for Table methods not specifically relate to scenarios using the Table class? ([example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setAttributes(Object)))

**03)**  *Bonus Question:*  Why is there a [getRow(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getRow(Integer)) Table method and not a `getColumn(columnIndex)` method?  How can you center all the contents of a column?

---

**Edit:**

As an aside, other similar attempts I make to apply styles don't work - I include them below as they may all point to a singular misunderstanding about how certain methods work.

a)  Trying to add 5 point space before paragraph through `MARGIN_TOP` - (result:  all other styles are applied, except for `MARGIN_TOP`):

```
var title_text = body.insertParagraph(2,"Hello");
title_style = {};
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Roboto Condensed';
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#999999';
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_TOP] = 5;  // DOESN'T WORK  
title_text.setAttributes(title_style);
```

However, this works:

```
title_text.setSpacingBefore(5);
```

b)  Trying to change the background color of a table (result: the background color of the paragraph changes, not the table):

```
another_table_style = {};
another_table_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#cfe2f3";
var another_table = body.appendTable(some_cells);
another_table.setAttributes(another_table_style);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the docs - some attributes are only for certain elements. For instance, the padding Enum is only for table *cells*, not entire tables.

To apply changes to entire tables, you can loop through the table cell elements and apply a calculated padding (or static).

*Bonus 1* - Not sure. Attributes in sheets are set individually on `Range` elements.

*Bonus 2* - Columns are children of rows. So, to iterate, you need to use two loops. You can set the background of a `TABLE_CELL` element using the Enum.

```js
function table() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var cells = [['Row 1.1', 'Row 1.2'], ['Row 2.1','Row 2.2']];

  var header_table = body.insertTable(0, cells);

  var styles = {};
  styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 20; // only applies to table cells
  styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#00ffff"


  Logger.log(header_table.getType());
  var rows = header_table.getNumRows();

  Logger.log(rows); // check the number of rows in your table

  // for each row...
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++) {

    // for each column...
    var cols = header_table.getRow(i).getNumChildren();

    for(var j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      var cell = header_table.getRow(i).getCell(j);

      // Set the TableCell attributes to each
      cell.setAttributes(styles)
    }
  }
}
```

I tested the `MARGIN` Enums and I think they only apply to the document `Body`, which contradicts the docs a little bit.

```js
function setMargins() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  var margins = {};

  margins[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_TOP] = 150;
  margins[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_LEFT] = 150;

  // uncomment the next line to set margins on the document body.
//  body.setAttributes(margins);

  // this returns all text elements in the doc, even those in tables
  var pars = body.getParagraphs(); 

  // According to the docs, this should work, but it doesn't.
  for(var i=0; i<pars.length; i++) {
    pars[i].setAttributes(margins);
  }
}
```